# GDAL Virtual File System (vsitar, vsizip, vsicurl) not working

Tags: gdal

I want to access a landsat tar file like :

```
gdalinfo "/vsitar/vsicurl/https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth/hsm/lsat1/collection01/oli_tirs/T1/2018/146/039/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz?id=ndauj8dbfj9tgucjgsu0l38sst&iid=LC81460392018019LGN00&did=543821091&ver=production"
```

But in my case it is not working.

```
enterERROR 4: '/vsitar/vsicurl/https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth/hsm/lsat1/collection01/oli_tirs/T1/2018/146/039/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz?id=ndauj8dbfj9tgucjgsu0l38sst&iid=LC81460392018019LGN00&did=543821091&ver=production' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/vsitar/vsicurl/https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth/hsm/lsat1/collection01/oli_tirs/T1/2018/146/039/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz?id=ndauj8dbfj9tgucjgsu0l38sst&iid=LC81460392018019LGN00&did=543821091&ver=production
```

In a ftp in my LAN it is working fine.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't open it using `/vsigzip//vsicurl/` or `/vsitar//vsicurl/`.

It's a tar.gz of multiple files.  Your best option is to download it (manually or you can script with `curl` or `wget`, or in python via the `requests` library).  Once you have downloaded it, you can use `/vsitar/` to read it:

```
gdalinfo /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz

ERROR 4: `/vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz'.
Unable to open source `/vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz' directly.
The archive contains 14 files:
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B1.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B2.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B3.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B4.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B5.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B6.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B7.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B8.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B9.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B10.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B11.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_BQA.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_ANG.txt
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_MTL.txt

gdalinfo /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B11.TIF

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_B11.TIF
       /vsitar/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1_MTL.txt
Size is 7781, 7911
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",81],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32644"]]
Origin = (122385.000000000000000,3474015.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
  METADATATYPE=ODL
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  122385.000, 3474015.000) ( 77d 1'54.67"E, 31d20'21.52"N)
Lower Left  (  122385.000, 3236685.000) ( 77d 7' 1.25"E, 29d12' 9.48"N)
Upper Right (  355815.000, 3474015.000) ( 79d29' 0.67"E, 31d23'30.36"N)
Lower Right (  355815.000, 3236685.000) ( 79d30'58.14"E, 29d15' 2.88"N)
Center      (  239100.000, 3355350.000) ( 78d17'13.77"E, 30d18' 6.61"N)
Band 1 Block=7781x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Sir I tried but it is giving this error. ERROR 4: `/vsigzip//vsicurl/https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth/hsm/lsat1/collection01/oli_tirs/T1/2018/146/039/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz?id=ndauj8dbfj9tgucjgsu0l38sst&iid=LC81460392018019LGN00&did=543821091&ver=production' not recognized as a supported file format.

Comment: But sir , when to just click on the link https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth/hsm/lsat1/collection01/oli_tirs/T1/2018/146/039/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz?id=ndauj8dbfj9tgucjgsu0l38sst&iid=LC81460392018019LGN00&did=543821091&ver=production it is downloading . Actually I am student of a institution . Is it possible that LAN of the institution is blocking access through vsigzip.

Comment: Actually sir this link https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth/hsm/lsat1/collection01/oli_tirs/T1/2018/146/039/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz?id=ndauj8dbfj9tgucjgsu0l38sst&iid=LC81460392018019LGN00&did=543821091&ver=production is generated from my login. If I remove the parameters and take only https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth/hsm/lsat1/collection01/oli_tirs/T1/2018/146/039/LC08_L1TP_146039_20180119_20180206_01_T1.tar.gz I also the same error you get. I have to use the whole link.

Comment: The link with your credentials does not work anymore. I suggest to put some tar+gzipped file into an open http server first and use that for experimenting. I am not sure what kind of chain is needed to read with curl a gzipped archive, that contains tar compredded file.